# VBA - Subscript out of Range when Workbooks().Close

Tags: vba, excel, file-io

I would like to loop through all excel workbooks in a folder and write the string "Test" in Cell A1 of every sheet of every workbook.
The following code results in 'Subscript out of Range(Error 9)'.
When I ran the code line by line it turned out the Error is caused by the
line: 
`Workbooks(FName).Close Savechanges:=True` 
 `Dir("C\...")` stored in `FName` returns just the file name so the error can't be because of giving the full path name to `Workboooks(...).Close` which seems often to be the reason for the error.
**On top of that** this code really opens the workbook instead of *just* writing into it. I don't want it
to open visually.

```
Sub multWB()

Dim FName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim directory As String

directory = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\multipleWorkbooks\"
FName = Dir("C:\Users\...\Desktop\multipleWorkbooks\*.xls*")

Do While FName <> ""


            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(directory & FName)
                   For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
                    sht.Cells(1, 1) = "Test"
                   Next
            FName = Dir

            Workbooks(FName).Close Savechanges:=True 'causes error


Loop
     Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try just doing `Workbooks(FName).Close True`

Comment: @dwirony I tried that, but error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving the name of the next workbook before closing the current open one. Switch the order those two lines of code:

```
        Workbooks(FName).Close Savechanges:=True 
        FName = Dir()
```

Comment: What is `Dir` even doing in this code anyways with no filepath following it?

Comment: At line "FName = Dir("C:\Users\...\Desktop\multipleWorkbooks\*.xls*")", he is initiating a search for all Office 97-2003 style .xls workbooks in the multipleWorkbooks directory. Calling Dir() the next time retrieves the next result from the search.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a reference to the workbook with `wb`. Just *use* that reference!

```
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Anything else is dereferencing objects for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

This: `FName = Dir` is missing the folder name. Change it to this:

`FName = directory & Dir()`

Comment: (a) That would currently create an infinite loop because `FName` would never equal `""`.  (b) The original code is already concatenating the path and filename together in the one spot where they should be combined (`Workbooks.Open(directory & FName)`)